# How to analyse/calculate circumference of human body parts from point cloud or 3d objects?

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, point-cloud-library

I am using win10, python and c#. I want to calculate circumference of human parts (belly, biceps etc) with using point cloud or 3d scans like .stl .obj .ply. Now I can get the point cloud of human body with kinect v2. I have point cloud of human body, scanned 3d human body in .stl .obj .ply formats.

I need some ideas and infos about it. I don't know how to analyse the things I have and how to calculate what I want.

Here I found an example of what I am trying to do but It doesn't need to be perfectly stable like that, Its for a school homework. Maybe you can give me some ideas about how to achieve my goal. Thank you for your help.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=48&v=jOvaZGloNRo

I get 3d scanned object with kinect v2 and use PCL to convert it into point cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about using PCL with Python or C#. In general you are looking at the following steps:

1. Filtering the points to the interested region
2. Segmenting the shape
3. Extracting the parameters

If you're interested in only Python, then OpenCV might be the best option. You can also develop the core logic in C++ and wrap it for Python or C#. C++ also has some nice UI libaries (Qt, [nanogui](https://github.com/wjakob/nanogui)), please see the following details for achieving the objective with PCL

### Filtering

[`CropBox`](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_crop_box.html) or [`PassThrough`](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_pass_through.html) can be used for this. It'll result in similar results as shown in the image assuming that the frame has been chosen properly. If not, the points cloud can be easily [transformed](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/group__common.html#ga52d532f7f2b4d7bba78d13701d3a33d8)

### Segmenting the shape

Assuming you want an average circumference, you might need to experiment with Circle 2D, Circle 3D and Cylinder models. More details regarding usage and API are [here](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/group__sample__consensus.html). The method chosen can be simple SAC (Sample Consensus) like RANSAC (Random SAC) or advanced method like LMEDS (Least Median of Squares) or MLESAC (Max Likelihood Estimation SAC)

### Extracting the parameters

All models have a radius field which can be used to find the circumference using standard formula (2*`pi`*`r`)

**Disclaimer**: Please take note that the shape is circular, not ellipse and the cylinder are right angled cylinders. So if the object measured (arm, or bicep) is not circular, the computed value might not be close to ground truth in extreme cases